# Hosted TFS Change Process Template

Tags: tfs

We have recently moved our TFS to be hosted @ visualstudio.com.
Initially we selected Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 2.2
We want to change this to MSF for agile development 6.2

Is there an easy way to do this.

Please note this is using the hosted TFS solution from Microsoft.

Comment: I don't think there is currently a way to do this as of today.